# Проблема с кавычками в C#

Tags: c#, кавычки

Нужно вставить переменные в код распаковки архива, но там много знаков и я очень сильно путаюсь, подставьте в этот код, взамен 2-ух путей, 2-е переменные (порядок не важен):

```
string extractpath = (string)gp.GetValue(valueName);
string filename = openFileDialog.FileName;
Process proc = Process.Start("WinRAR.exe", @"e ""D:\Games\steam\steamapps\common\Skyrim Special Edition\b.rar"" ""D:\Games\steam\steamapps\common\Skyrim Special Edition""");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот так, попробуйте

```
string extractpath = (string)gp.GetValue(valueName);
string filename = openFileDialog.FileName;
Process proc = Process.Start("WinRAR.exe", $"e \"{fileName}\" \"{extractPath}\"");
```

[$ — интерполяция строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)